# Knockout Design

Tags: c#, javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm relatively new to java-script and knockout. 
I've done the getting started tutorials and im ready to start designing my application.

My question:
My DTO(s) coming back from my web service is a mix of simple "Contact" and "Address" information, but also more complex information. A document DTO as an example will typically look something like this.

```
public partial class GoodsDeclaration : Document
{
public long identifierField { get; set; }
public bool identifierFieldSpecified { get; set; }
public System.DateTime acceptanceDateTimeField { get; set; }
public bool acceptanceDateTimeFieldSpecified { get; set; }
public Code statusField { get; set; }
public Code declarationOfficeField { get; set; }
public Party declarantField { get; set; }
public Code agentRoleField { get; set; }
public Party agentField { get; set; }
public Party exporterField { get; set; }
public Party importerField { get; set; }
public Party suretyField { get; set; }
public Party domesticDutyPayerField { get; set; }
public Amount totalInvoiceAmountField { get; set; }
public Quantity totalNumberOfGovernmentAgencyGoodsItemsField { get; set; }
public Measure totalNettMassField { get; set; }
public Measure totalGrossMassField { get; set; }
public Quantity totalNumberOfPackagesField { get; set; }
public Quantity totalNumberOfSealsAffixedField { get; set; }
public GovernmentProcedure governmentProcedureField { get; set; }
}
```

The above Document will be bind to the UI, the complex types like "importerField typeof Party" will use Name as display text and ID as hidden or tag value.

Any suggestions on the structure of MVVM, will I create one model for Document or split it and then have a ViewModel to bring it together?

I'm trying to get my head around the best guidelines to use when dealing with big nested complex types and how to implement the MVVM pattern specificaly to Knockout.

The Json object

```
{"AcceptanceDateTime":"2008-11-15T18:52:58",
"AcceptanceDateTimeSpecified":true,
"Status":{"CodeListGuid":"EAA4E08F-540A-4D97-9A93-DB53DCC63A41","Name":"ACCEPTED"},
"DeclarationOffice":{"CodeListGuid":"91B82FB4-6642-4A96-80D0-880EC5164BC3","Name":"LUANDA IA"},
"Declarant":{"Guid":"fe1d31ac-ba79-44df-a6a7-5df5664d3991","Name":"Baby Inc."},
"AgentRole":{"CodeListGuid":"BD9619B9-81C1-4B3B-8CB7-377155BB4885","Name":"AGENT_ONLY"},
"Agent":{"Guid":"9eba4f49-2451-4396-89d8-778b1a24e09d","Name":"Clickabox Pty Ltd"},
"Exporter":{"Guid":"866b2b1b-d111-429d-965a-f175a422e7dc","Name":"Toys R You Inc"},
"Importer":{"Guid":"da856549-853d-4802-8049-5aa2e356e463","Name":"ABC Chemicals"},
"Surety":{"Guid":"fe1d31ac-ba79-44df-a6a7-5df5664d3991","Name":"Baby Inc."},
"DomesticDutyPayer":{"Guid":"8ff88e7c-5dc1-42df-9278-4e6d8cc65d48","Name":"Hunters Pty Ltd"},
"BankAccount":{"InstitutionName":"ABSA","AccountNumber":"1523689987-20125"},
"TotalInvoiceAmount":{"Currency":{"CodeListGuid":"154752B1-D312-4EA6-95FA-A994F3F28704","Name":"KZ"},"Content":1000.00},
"TotalNumberOfGovernmentAgencyGoodsItems":{"UnitCode":{"CodeListGuid":"9462E0EE-D993-4DE5-A7D8-35C3EFF8E920","Name":"TOTAL"},"Content":10},
"TotalNettMass":{"UnitCode":{"CodeListGuid":"dedit qui foedere","Name":"magno cum"},"Content":1000.00},
"TotalGrossMass":{"UnitCode":{"CodeListGuid":"ac terras","Name":"regemque dedit"},"Content":1000.00},
"TotalNumberOfPackages":{"UnitCode":{"CodeListGuid":"infixit acuto","Name":"tenens mollitque animos"},"Content":10},
"TotalNumberOfSealsAffixed":{"UnitCode":{"CodeListGuid":"montis insuper","Name":"habenas ipsa"},"Content":10},
"GovernmentProcedure":{"RequestedGovernmentProcedure":{"CodeListGuid":"mollitque animos","Name":"iovisque et"},
"PreviousGovernmentProcedure":{"CodeListGuid":"soror et coniunx","Name":"iunonis adorat"}},

"GoodsShipment":{"Guid":"adorat praeterea",
"SequenceNumber":10,
"UniqueConsignmentReference":{"Identification":"illum exspirantem transfixo","TraderAssignedReference":"aris imponet honorem"},
"Invoice":{"Guid1":"nimborum in","InvoiceNumber":"vasto rex","InvoiceType":{"CodeListGuid":"flammato secum","Name":"tempestatesque sonoras"},
"InvoiceDate":"2008-10-09T00:00:00","Guid":"aris imponet","Identification":"premere et",
"Type":{"CodeListGuid":"insuper altos","Name":"ferant rapidi secum"}},
"Buyer":{"Guid":"8e96872d-75f4-4817-8101-4259ddd21605","Name":"One World Logistics"},
"Seller":{"Guid":"ee0b408b-825c-492e-8820-87e84fe0e527","Name":"Sports Car Inc."},
"DeliveryDestination":{"Guid":"profundum quippe ferant","Name":"imposuit regemque"},
"TransactionNature":{"CodeListGuid":"magno cum","Name":"iras ni faciat"},
"Consignment":{"Guid":"verrantque per","Consignor":{"Guid":"metuens molemque","Name":"dare iussus habenas"},
"Consignee":{"Guid":"214e85a0-e750-48a0-bf92-bcce9d2d14f6","Name":"ACME Plastic"},
"UltimateConsignee":{"Guid":"5371e4f6-7ad1-421a-a6e9-43bd2e6a9084","Name":"Spices of the world cc"},
"Carrier":{"Guid":"f0247983-5742-429a-9a6b-eaeb13dea9ee","Name":"BBnB cc"},
"TransportContractDocument":{"Guid":"auras sed","Identification":"aequora ventis illum",
"Type":{"CodeListGuid":"aequora ventis","Name":"et coniunx"}},

"TransportEquipmentList":[{"Guid":"incedo regina iovisque","SequenceNumber":10,"Identification":"hic vasto rex","Name":"ego quae","SealNumber":"tempestatesque sonoras"}],

"BorderTransportMeans":{"Guid":"ego quae divum","Name":"aris imponet honorem","Identification":"molemque et",
"RegistrationNationality":{"CodeListGuid":"rapidum iaculata e","Name":"nimborum in"},
"Type":{"CodeListGuid":"altos imposuit regemque","Name":"aeoliam venit"}},
"Item":{"Guid":"hic vasto","Name":"et laxas","Identification":"carcere frenat",
"RegistrationNationality":{"CodeListGuid":"murmure montis circum","Name":"maria ac"},
"Type":{"CodeListGuid":"imponet honorem talia","Name":"numen iunonis"}},
"ItemElementName":0,"Item1":{"CodeListGuid":"talia flammato","Name":"terras caelumque"},
"Item1ElementName":0,"GoodsLocation":{"CodeListGuid":"vasto rex aeolus","Name":"arce sceptra"},
"TotalNumberOfPackages":{"UnitCode":{"CodeListGuid":"luctantis ventos","Name":"bella gero"},"Content":10}},
"TradeTerms":{"Condition":{"CodeListGuid":"ac vinclis et","Name":"imposuit regemque"},
"CountryRelationship":{"CodeListGuid":"ignem disiecitque rates","Name":"et premere"},
"Location":{"CodeListGuid":"murmure montis","Name":"premere et"}},
"Payer":{"Guid":"2b62b4b1-e617-4bb6-a8c0-149ae8f72293","Name":"Fish Tackle Pty Ltd"},
"Item":{"CodeListGuid":"premere et","Name":"insuper altos"},
"ItemElementName":0,
"Warehouse":{"CodeListGuid":"iovis rapidum","Name":"indignantes magno"},
"ExportationCountry":{"CodeListGuid":"sonoras imperio","Name":"rapidum iaculata e"},
"CustomsValuation":{"PartyRelationship":{"CodeListGuid":"auras sed","Name":"iovisque et"},
"EUValuationDetails":{"CodeListGuid":"flammato secum dea","Name":"hic vasto rex"}}},

"AdditionalInformationList":[{"Guid":"aeoliam venit",
"Content":"altos imposuit regemque",
"Statement":{"CodeListGuid":"profundum quippe","Name":"premit ac vinclis"},
"StatementType":{"CodeListGuid":"luctantis ventos","Name":"luctantis ventos tempestatesque"}}],

"Guid":"gero et",
"Identification":"sonoras imperio",
"Type":{"CodeListGuid":"5BA6634F-CD9F-4818-8B66-15E50AFCA5DA","Name":"IMPORT_A"}}
```

Comment: You can start with the knockout mapping plugin : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Hi RaoTorS, did not see you there, looking at it. Im just wondering if it would not be better to split the nested object, feels like it might  be difficult managing such a big deep nested object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout mapping plugin will be very useful in your case. You won't have to write the view model for your DTO. It will handle it.It's also useful for easy maintenance. You can check the [docs here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Assuming you are getting your object `GoodsDeclaration` as json from your web service, you will to need initialize your view model as follows.

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(returnedJson);
```

if your code deserialize the data into a JavaScript object then you can use

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsObject);
```

then you will be able to access your variables like this

```
var example = myGoodsDeclaration.identifierField();
```

Comment: thx totto90, im looking at the documentation. will give you same feedback soon.